# how worksheet.saveas work in visual studio?

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2019, worksheet

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelPDF = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook MyWorkbookPDF = excelPDF.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\range rules - Copia.xlsx");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet MyWorkSheetPDF;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range MyCellPDF;

MyWorkSheetPDF = excelPDF.Worksheets[2];

MyWorkSheetPDF.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\NAMEFILE.PDF", format???,
        System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
        false, false,false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
        System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

What should I put in place of the 'format???'?

Comment: A good way to find the code you need is to use the "Record macro" feature, then look at the code it generated.  Takes you [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat) and tells you to use XlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF.

Comment: thanks.. but when i try there's a error :'value outside the expected range.' do you know why? if i try whit small file it works.

Comment: const int xlQualityStandard = 0;
                MyWorkSheetP.ExportAsFixedFormat(
                    Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
                    filename, xlQualityStandard, true, false,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing);

Answer (score 0):

Read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.saveas?view=vsto-2017):

> FileFormat - Object - The file format to use when you save the file. For a list of valid choices, see the [FileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.fileformat?view=vsto-2017#Microsoft_Office_Tools_Excel_Workbook_FileFormat) property.

The type of `FileFormat` is the [`XlFileFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat?view=excel-pia) enum

e.g. `XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook` for XSLX